# Can't change system font to custom font in Xcode 11 Beta

Tags: xcode11, macos-catalina

I'm trying to change the font of a UILabel to a custom font but the option is locked and says 'Custom (non installed)', but I do have custom fonts in fact it works fine in Xcode 10

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it's not working in XCode 11 beta but you can follow one workaround. Change text style from Plain to Attributed. It allows you to change the font.

Comment: But changing to attributed text, show default custom fonts and not the one we add manually.

Comment: @rajtharan-g Install the font on your mac and then change the font using Attributed option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it by install the font on the mac. It is also possible in the XML of the xib:

Add the following inside `<document>` tag. Usually bellow `</dependencies>` tag.

```
    <customFonts key="customFonts">
       <array key="Roboto-Medium.ttf">
            <string>Roboto-Medium</string>
        </array>
        <array key="Roboto-Regular.ttf">
            <string>Roboto-Regular</string>
        </array>
    </customFonts>
```

changing for your custom font.

And inside `<label>` tag:

```
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Roboto-Medium" family="Roboto" pointSize="18"/>
```

You should see something  like:

[Custom font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugpPr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Xcode 11 Beta 5. That solved it for me.